# Objective-C Associated Objects vs NSMapTable

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I recently discovered `NSMapTable` ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmaptable), [nshipster](http://nshipster.com/nshashtable-and-nsmaptable/)) and I have been wondering whether it can be used in place of associated objects.

Here's an example using standard associated objects:

```
var fooKey = "foo"
extension UIView {

  var foo: UIImage? {
    set {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &fooKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
    get {
      return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &fooKey) as? UIImage
    }
  }
}
```

versus an implementation using `NSMapTable`:

```
let barTable = NSMapTable<UIView, UIImage>(keyOptions: [.weakMemory], valueOptions: [.strongMemory])

extension UIView {

  var bar: UIImage? {
      get {
        return barTable.object(forKey: self)
      }
      set {
        barTable.setObject(newValue, forKey: self)
      }
  }
}
```

I tried to google and understand the differences with no luck, as I don't even know how I can compare the two implementations.

How can I compare them? What are the differences?

Thanks

Comment: bbum's answer gives one example of the difference between these two, but to get an answer that's specific to your needs, you're going to have to give some more specific examples of your use case — why do you need associated objects in the first place?

Comment: Nothing specific now, I was just trying to understand the technical differences and how to compare the two approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an object is deallocated, all objects that are associated with it using `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` will be released (and sometimes deallocated if that was the last strong reference).

Your `NSMapTable` example won't clean up on `dealloc`.

---

Beyond that, they are functionally the same, but have different implementation details.  The most significant is the threading policy;  `NSMapTable` is not thread safe whereas `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` is treated the same as an `@property(atomic, strong)`.

Comment: NSMapTable will also release the associated object if the keys are held weakly and the values are held strongly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the other way around: `objc_setAssociatedObject` can be used in place of `NSMapTable`. Instead of requiring a `NSMapTable` object to hold the references, the reference is stored on the object itself. And although associated objects allow categories to have properties as you demonstrated, in fact that removes powerful functionality. By wrapping it in a category means all `UIImage`s now have that key, whereas by defining the key in the controller now it can store things in `UIImage` that only it requires.